# use filtered data from 3 tables of database in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have (customers,customer fav , product) tables. that in customer fav table i have customerID and PorductID stored,that shows which product is fav of which customer. i want to show all products(with empty heart icon) in a page and if a customer has a fav product the icon of that product should be filled heart icon.

Here is my code:

**Contorller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ProductRepository BlProduct = new ProductRepository();
    CustomerRepository BlCustomer = new CustomerRepository();
    CustomerLikeRepository BlCusLike = new CustomerLikeRepository();
    var username = User.Identity.Name;
    var customer = BlCustomer.Where(x => x.Email == username).SingleOrDefault();
    var model = new HomeIndexViewModel();
    model.Products = BlProduct.Select();
    if(customer!=null)
    {
        model.Customer = customer;
        model.CostumerLikes = BlCusLike.Where(l=>l.CustomerId==customer.id).ToList();
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class HomeIndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MySIte.Models.DomainModels.Product> Products { get; set; }
    public MySIte.Models.DomainModels.Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MySIte.Models.DomainModels.CostumersLike> CostumerLikes { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Products)
{
    <div class="product-thumb clearfix" style="height:100%;">
        <a href="@item.id">
        @Html.ImageFor(modelItem => item.ImgUrl, new { width = "500" }, "Tulips.jpg", "Files", "UploadImages")
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="product-info clearfix">
            <span class="product-title">@item.Name</span>
            <div class="price">
                <del>
                    <span class="regular">$@item.Price.ToPrice()</span>
                </del>
                <ins>
                    <span class="amount">$@item.Price</span>
                </ins>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="add-to-cart text-center">
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@item.id"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>  quick  view</a>
        </div>
        @if (Model.Customer.Email==User.Identity.Name)
        { 
            <a href="#" class="addWish like" data-product="@item.id"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" style="color:red;"></i></a>
        }
    </li>
}
```

in view section there is an IF statement .thats the place i want to change the icon to "fa-heart" if it is customers fav.

How can i get the Customerslike data and check if customerid and product id is available in table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally got how to check if Customerid and productid exists in customerliked table or not.

in view i have to write the if statement like bellow:

**"if" part of view:**

```
@if (Model.Customer.Email == User.Identity.Name)
{
    if (Model.CostumerLikes.Where(x => x.ProductId == item.id && x.CustomerId== Model.Customer.id).Count()==1)
    {
        <a href="#" class="addWish like" data-product="@item.id" data-user="@Model.Customer.id">
            <i class="fa fa-heart" style="color:red;"></i>
        </a>
    }
       else
    {
        <a href="#" class="addWish like" data-product="@item.id"  data-user="@Model.Customer.id">
            <i class="fa fa-heart-o" style="color:red;"></i>
        </a>
    }
}
```